# Installing a package with cabal doesn't work (random)

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm using Windows 10. I downloaded Cabal.exe, put it in my `ghc-8.8.1\bin\` directory and ran it with command `cabal update`. It did nothing for a while, then it ended without any messages.

Now when I run `cabal install random` (trying to install package "random"), I get the following error:

`cabal: Error: Could not find module: System.Random with any suffix:
["gc","chs","hsc","x","y","ly","cpphs","hs","lhs","hsig","lhsig"]. If the
module is autogenerated it should be added to 'autogen-modules'.`

I have no clue why it does this.

I also tried installing the package manually (following the steps from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/How_to_install_a_Cabal_package)) - downloaded package random-1.1.tar.gz and ran:
`cd filepathtopackage
c:\Program Files\Apps\ghc-8.8.1\bin\runhaskell.exe Setup configure`

This for a change gives me the following error:

`| C:\Program Files\Apps\ghc-8.8.1\lib\Cabal-3.0.0.0\HSCabal-3.0.0.0.o: unknown symbol '.file'
Setup: Setup: unable to load package 'Cabal-3.0.0.0'`

When I run `ghc-pkg list`, Cabal is in there, so again, no clue why it does this.

Does anyone have any tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: Could be faulty installation. Case looks similar to https://github.com/ekmett/semigroupoids/issues/21

Comment: Also if you haven't tried it yet, [`stack`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) is my preferred tool nowadays.